# SQL Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2014, ef-core-2.2

I am using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` 2.2.6. I have a stored procedure which typically takes 1 to 2 seconds to execute.

I am using .NET Core 2.2 with EF Core to execute that stored procedure.

`appsettings.json`:

```
{  
    "SqlCommandTimeout": 120, // seconds
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=serverip;Database=MyDataBase;Integrated Security=True;"
    }
}
```

In `startup.cs` I am setting connection string and timeout

```
var sqlCommandTimeout = configuration.GetValue<int>("SqlCommandTimeout");
services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(sqlCommandTimeout));
        });
```

This code executes the stored procedure and populates a DTO:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<AvailableWorkDTO>> prcGetAvailableWork(this MyDBContext dbContext, int userID)
{            
    var timeout = dbContext.Database.GetCommandTimeout() ?? 120;

    var result = new List<AvailableWorkDTO>();

    using (var cmd = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {
        var p1 = new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int)
            {
                Value = userID
            };

        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.prcGetAvailableWork";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = timeout;

        await dbContext.Database.OpenConnectionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                var item = new AvailableWorkDTO();
                item.ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                item.Name = reader.GetString(1);
                item.Title = reader.GetString(2);
                item.Count = reader.GetInt32(3);

                result.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The stored procedure only reads data from couple of tables using `READUNCOMMITTED` isolation level. However there is also a another background process that inserts new records into these tables every 3 minutes.

**ISSUE**

Every now and then when number of users increase we are seeing the timeout exception.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.

> The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__122_0(Task`1 result)      at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at Data.Entities.StoredProcedures.StoredPrcedureExtensions.prcGetAvailableWork(MyDbContext dbContext, Int32 userID) in D:\Jenkins\xx-production\workspace\Src\Common\Data\Entities\StoredProcedures\StoredPrcedureExtensions.cs:line 56
> at   ....
> ....
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)

> at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> ClientConnectionId:c10da510-509f-4bfb-8b37-58c0ee8fa3b1
> Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11at

**Questions**

1. I am using EF Core 2.2. Based on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_CommandTimeout), for certain async methods `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` property is ignored. In the above code will the timeout ignored?
2. SQL Server Profiler shows stored procedure actually gets executed only once by `await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()` line. However we still need to keep connection open while reading from the reader. Is the `CommandTimeOut` includes time takes for reading from the reader?
3. At most 100 users may concurrently access this stored procedure. We have double check indexes and also execute scheduled indexing job every day. We are using

   ```
    Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64) Standard Edition (64-bit)
   ```

   on Windows Server 2019. Which should be able to handle the load. Is there any settings that we need to look? (SQL Server also has multiple other databases as well)

Comment: perhaps [`explain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/explain-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) might help to show any potential bottlenecks

Comment: @jspcal its applies to Azure Synapse Analytics. We are not using Azure

Comment: A timeout could be caused by locks being held for too long. Ideally you should find the source of such blocking and fix that, rather than increasing the timeout unreasonably. Side point: you should have `dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()` in a `using` block also

Comment: Is it not true, when command disposes the underline connection also dispose?

Answer (score 3):

> In the above code will the timeout ignored?

No.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.
```

This is a client-side timeout caused by the CommandTimeout.

> Is the CommandTimeOut includes time takes for reading from the reader?

Yes.  Per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), SqlCommand.CommandTimeout includes SqlDataReader.Read() time.

> Is there any settings that we need to look?

Turn on the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=The%20SQL%20Server%20Query%20Store%20feature%20provides%20you,runtime%20statistics%2C%20and%20retains%20these%20for%20your%20review.) and track the [session wait stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to see if you're seeing blocking, CPU contention or something else.

Comment: Is there any command in EF Core that loads entire data set. Like in Full .NET we have DataAdapter.fill method?

Comment: Does SQL server caches the result of the stored proc and then returns one row at a time? Profiler show SP gets executed only once? So now sure why we have to read data one row at a time and leave the connection open

Comment: ToList loads the entire result.  SqlServer streams the results as they are available, but some plans have blocking operators, so don’t start sending results right away.

Comment: Understood. But ToList() is not available when executing stored proc. The only option is  to use SqlReader to read the result from SP. What I am not understanding is, the `ExecuteReaderAsync` method executes the Stored  Proc only once, but reader reads record one by one.. Where is the result stored in between? From where reader is reading the records?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, in my case I written the stored procedure code in the following way

```
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
  some code here....
 --COMMIT TRAN // it is missed or written in the wrong place
END TRY
```

**"COMMIT TRAN" code missed in the stored procedure code but "BEGIN TRAN" is  there**, due to that previous calls are in waiting state and for the next transaction server will not respond